# Link titles - Any best practices you could cite?

Tags: links

When building `<a href title="">` tags, are there any formal or informal UX&SEO best practices you ever came across into ? Please season your answer with as much experience detailing as possible,

I had the feeling that if your site is multilingual and is not English by nativity, it is good to create English link-titles as a quality factor == It helps visitors who does not speak the sites language to navigate better and might be better than machine-translation as hopefully they would see a quite clear English explanation about the link **when they hover on it**. Your thoughts on this theory are also welcome,

Comment: Best practices for what?   User experience, SEO, legal compliance?

Comment: I've edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>The description is an invalid attribute for the anchor tag don't use it.
Use title instead.</strike>

**Updated answer**

The title attribute is used to show the title of the page that is linked to. You can perhaps put in the original language title and then the english translation, so it'll be displayed on hover.

This is what the title attribute is used for:
OPTIONAL. This is informational only. If present the value of this field should equal the value of the TITLE of the document whose address is given by the HREF attribute.

So using the title in an anchor tag you should put the title of the page you're linking to. That'll be best practice and valid mark up.

https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/1995-archive/Elements/A.html

Here are a few more supported attributes for html5.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp

And these are the global attributes supported. 
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp

Comment: I find this usage problematic as the <title> tags of the linked pages can change: I guess the search-engine companies takes that for granted and thus does not force people that the link hovering-titile will surly be identical to the <title> tags of the linked pages...